# Cloning an android emulator with all user data including google account

Tags: android, android-emulator

I intend to create a new emulator from an existing one, the emulator/device id needs to be different but the remaining data including the applications installed and the registered google accounts should persist in new emulator.

Can anyone point me in right direction

Tried loading userdata.img file of the emulator to be cloned into a new emulator with -data option. Did not work. May be I am not doing it in correct manner??

./emulator -avd **new existing emulator name** -data **path/to/emulator/tobe/cloned/userdata.img**

Thanks

--
JR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The image to be used is userdata-qemu.img instead of userdata.img. All the userdata is persisted. The snapshot option needs to be disabled in old emulator for this to work.

./emulator -avd **new existing emulator name** -data **path/to/emulator/tobe/cloned/userdata-qemu.img**

Thanks.

--
JR

Answer (score 1):

1. Open AVD Manager.
2. Select an AVD.
3. Click <kbd>Edit...</kbd>
4. Change *Name*

You will see a message: *The AVD 'avd-name' will be duplicated into 'another-avd-name'.*

<kbd>Edit AVD</kbd> will become <kbd>Create AVD</kbd>. Click it.

Comment: Thanks..had tried doing that but did not work, it just the duplicates the emulator, the user data like apps and google accounts is not persisted in the new emulator